# NestedScrollView, fillViewPort, LinearLayout and no scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a puzzle for you today.

Why this sample doesn't scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

yet this does (mind the height of `TextView` set to more than the height of the screen).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How you would fix this? Also, no custom views that fix `NestedScrollView` are allowed :)

Comment: When we set height as `match_parent` to child views of `NestedScrollView` it shows first `match_parent` height child view as single child, If we need to scroll multiple child views then we need to add  height as `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i went with CoordinatorLayout and custom Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview will only scroll when it is necessary it will not scroll when it can fit it's child in the screen